# Is there a better way than using SQL Cursor for dynamic string replace on large volume set

Tags: sql, t-sql, optimization

I really need some help or direction making the below more optimised as I am not an SQL developer and the below takes too long to complete.
I have looked into a few different alternatives to cursors as I read they are not the best to work on large data sets, but I haven't seen an alternative for what I need to do, as I don't believe nested REPLACE for example will work as what I need to replace is dynamic based on record lookups.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is replace any found ids that can be found within 3 columns inside a table with the new ids based on the mapping (old & new) that are in another 3 tables.
I have no idea which row these ids are in and how frequent.

So what I wrote is to build a single mapping temporary table, iterate through that table and the do a string replace on the 3 columns for wherever the original Id is found (sourceId) and replace it with the new Id (TargetId).

--update: What I'm trying to do is replace old ids that are inside 3 large json fields (500+chars), with new Ids. There's no risk of incorrect mapping as each id is unique even across the source and target tables and are always 18 nchar long, so cannot be inside another, i.e cant be 10 inside 110.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

For info, after the 3 tables have fed into the RefIds temporary table then RefIds_TempTable is around 800,000 rows.
The Order table that has the 3 replace functions applied is around 200,000 rows.

```
DECLARE @RefCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @SourceID nchar(18);
DECLARE @TargetID nchar(18);
BEGIN
    -- copy refids into temp table

    -- declare temp table
    Create Table #RefIds_TempTable (SourceID nchar(18) Primary Key, TargetID nchar(18))

    Insert Into #RefIds_TempTable (SourceID, TargetID)
    Select b.id, a.id
    From [target database].dbo.[Product] a
    Join [source database].dbo.[Product] b
    On b.ProductCode = a.ProductCode

    Insert Into #RefIds_TempTable (SourceID, TargetID)
    Select b.id, a.id
    From [target database].dbo.[AttributeCategory] a
    Join [source database].dbo.[AttributeCategory] b
    On b.Code = a.Code

    Insert Into #RefIds_TempTable (SourceID, TargetID)
    Select b.id, a.id
    From [target database].dbo.[Attribute] a
    Join [source database].dbo.[Attribute] b
    On b.Code = a.Code

    Insert Into #RefIds_TempTable (SourceID, TargetID)
    Select b.id, a.id
    From [target database].dbo.[Assignment] a
    Join [source database].dbo.[Assignment] b
    On b.Key = a.Key

    BEGIN

        SET @RefCursor = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY STATIC FOR
        select SourceID, TargetID from #RefIds_TempTable

        OPEN @RefCursor 
            FETCH NEXT FROM @RefCursor INTO @SourceID, @TargetID;
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                BEGIN
                    Update [target database].dbo.Orders
                    set JSONValue = REPLACE(JSONValue, @SourceID,@TargetID)

                    Update [target database].dbo.Orders
                    set JSONStr = REPLACE(JSONStr, @SourceID,@TargetID)

                    Update [target database].dbo.Orders
                    set FullJSON = REPLACE(FullJSON, @SourceID,@TargetID)
            FETCH NEXT FROM @RefCursor INTO @SourceID, @TargetID 
        END; 
    End;
    CLOSE @RefCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @RefCursor;
END;
```

Example of cut down JSONStr value (Usually contains many more attributes etc):

```
{
  "ABC": [
    {
      "AttributDefStart": null,
      "objId": "99t9Z1234561AbLPJK",
      "attri": "44t9Z1234561AbLGTY",
      "catId": "Y9V2U368714EUFFQWQ",
      "cde": "ABC",
      "catnme": "provs",
      "AttributDefEnd": null
    },
    {
      "AttributDefStart": null,
      "objId": "99t9Z1234561AbLPJK",
      "attri__c": "98G7Z136900XZB0FFT",
      "catId": "Y9V2U368714EUFFQWQ",
      "cde": "ABC",
      "catnme": "provs",
      "AttributDefEnd": null
    }
  ]
}
```

And if I had these id mappings for example:
SourceId = 99t9Z1234561AbLPJK
and TargetId = 33J9Z1234561AbLLTG

then I would expect the JSON to contain the TargetId values wherever the sourceId existed.

Comment: Cursors are almost always the worst option, especially for lots of data. You can write an `INSERT ... SELECT` or `UPDATE target ..,FROM source INNER JOIN target ..` query to update a table based on the results of a query

Comment: yep, I keep reading they are not the best option, however as someone who hasn't done much SQL coding, I have no other option that works for my situation, for example, I don't know how to write and Update target .., From Source solution that does a string replace of values from a lookup table... ?

Comment: Why do you think this is even an option? What is this code trying to do? The code you wrote is far more complicated than an INSERT or UPDATE clause, and very hard to read for anyone that doesn't know what your application does, what the tables and columns are.

Comment: Explain *in the question itself* what you want to do, not how you think it can be done. You have some tables named Orders, Assignment and Attribute. Those have some JSON fields. What are you trying to do with them? PS: you can modify multiple fields in a single UPDATE, no need to execute 3 updates just to modify 3 fields

Comment: The code you have currently written will update *EVERY ROW* in the `Orders` table each iteration of the cursor. Only the final iteration (if it ever makes it that far) will be reflected in the table. So you iterate 800000 times, each time updating 200k records, 3 times over which means 4.8x10^11 updates , but only the last iteration does anything.  Please explain what you are trying to do because 1) cursors aren't the best way (which you already know) 2) the code you provided doesn't do what you want it to do, so we can't even reverse engineer at this point.

Comment: Probably easier to shred and rebuild the JSONs using joins. Can you give an actual example with a few rows of data?

Comment: sorry, i've updated the post adding more context.
Essentially there is a temp table with old Ids and new Ids, and I need to replace those old ids that could be anywhere in Json of those 3 fields and replace them with the new ids

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I read somewhere you couldn't use replace on more than one column per update, was this incorrect then?

Comment: Yes. `REPLACE` is just a string function. You still haven't explained what you're doing. It looks like you want to replace ID values in JSON fields so they match a target database. That's a *very* risky operation - what if two tables have the same ID value? What if one ID is a substring of another, eg `10` and `101` ?

Comment: you are right, that is what im trying to do, replace old ids that are inside 3 large json fields (500+chars), with new ids.
There's no risk as each id is unique even across the source and target tables, and are always 18 nchar long, so cannot be inside another.
-- and thank you for responding as it's helping me better form my question

Comment: Can we have actual sample data?

Comment: @Charlieface let me construct some, I cant copy and paste it, as it needs obfuscating first.

Comment: @Charlieface I've added some JSON example, but it's stripped down as otherwise would be 500/600 lines.

Comment: Is the `ABC` key (directly under the root and containing an array) dynamic or fixed? If dynamic can there multiple of it?

Comment: @Charlieface dynamic and there will be multiple objects, so there could be: ABC :[], FGT[], GHU[].

Comment: @JNevill I don't understand why only the last iteration does anything, doesn't the UPDATE...SET... save the field each time?
Yes, most of the time I guess the field is unchanged if it hasn't found that string to replace, but it's still saved to the table?

Comment: @ukprogrammer `Update [target database].dbo.Orders
                    set JSONValue = REPLACE(JSONValue, @SourceID,@TargetID)` Says to update each row in `Orders` table setting its `JSONValue` column to whatever that `REPLACE()` spits out for the current cursor values. Since there is no `WHERE` to filter WHICH rows of `Orders` are updated, it runs it for all of them. Over and over again. In short, there is no defined relationship between your temp table, or rather the cursors current value, and the `Orders` table so the whole `Orders` set is affected (times 3).

Comment: @JNevill ah, understood. Yeah, there's no relationship because I have no idea which row(s) each SourceId is in and therefore needs replacing, unless there's a way to add a where clause based on if the string is found, could I perhaps use CHARINDEX(@SourceID,  JSONValue) != 0
I also didn't know I could use REPLACE on multiple columns in a single update as I had read it couldn't but I now know different. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When complex JSON modifications are involved, it's often easier to shred the JSON, make the joins and rebuild.

Unfortunately, this is made more complex because the JSON has dynamic keys and SQL Server does not have `JSON_AGG` so we need to hack it with `STRING_AGG` and `STRING_ESCAPE`

```
UPDATE t
SET JsonStr = j.newJson

FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (

    SELECT newJson =      -- re-aggregate the JSON using dynamic keys
      '{' +
       STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(j2.[key], 'json') + '":"' + newJson.json), ',') +
      '}'

    FROM OPENJSON(t.JsonStr) j1     -- shred the array into [key] (which is index) and [value]
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.value)  -- shred the values
      WITH (
        AttributDefStart varchar(100),
        objId varchar(100),
        attri varchar(100),
        catId varchar(100),
        cde varchar(100),
        catnme varchar(100),
        AttributDefEnd varchar(100)
      ) j2

    LEFT JOIN [source database].dbo.[Product] pS
        JOIN [target database].dbo.[Product] pT ON pT.ProductCode = pS.ProductCode
      ON pS.id = j2.objId

    LEFT JOIN [target database].dbo.[AttributeCategory] cS
        JOIN [source database].dbo.[AttributeCategory] cT ON cT.Code = cS.Code
      ON cS.id = j2.catId

    LEFT JOIN [target database].dbo.[Attribute] aS
        JOIN [source database].dbo.[Attribute] aT ON aT.Code = aS.Code
      ON aS.id = j2.attri

    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
          j2.AttributDefStart,
          objId = pT.id,
          attri = aT.id,
          catId = cT.id,
          j2.cde,
          j2.catnme,
          j2.AttributDefEnd
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER  -- rebuild as single objects
    ) newJson(json)

) j
```

You may want to change the data types of the `OPENJSON` schema.

You also may want to change the `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER`. Alternatively you may want to filter out cases where the join fails.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, I 'think' I understand this and will try this tomorrow.